# How to check text in parallel div s using for loop in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, text, contains

I am the very beginner of Selenium. I want to check text in parallel 'div's.
The number of div changes at each time.

I used `find_elements_by_xpath('\\div[{}][contains(text(),"tex")]'.format()`

However, there is and error as below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:  
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1/div[4]/div[4]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2][contains(text(),"FAMILY")]"}
```

Actually, there is a 'FAMILY' text (I've checked in a browser)

Do you have any idea?

Here is my code:

```
while True:

Num_of_Divs = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("./html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div/form/div/div[1]/div"))-1 # num of divs changes and default value is 1

if Num_of_Divs == 0 :
    browser.refresh() 
else :
    for j in range(1,Num_of_Divs ):
        Checker1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[{}]/div[2][contains(text(),"FAMILY")]'.format(j+1))
        Checker2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[{}]/div[5]'.format(j+1)).text 
        if (Checker1 == [])&(Checker2 == 'ADULT'):
            element1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/input')
            element1.click()
            element2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/input[1]')
            element2.click()
        pass
browser.refresh() 

breaking_point = check_exists_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/h1')
if breaking_point == True: 
    print('FINISH!')
    break
pass
```

The error occurs at Checker 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[contains(text(), 'FAMILY')]
```

Use above XPATH and check.